# Error running pipeline in Github Actions with latest .NET 6 (6.0.300)

Tags: .net, msbuild, github-actions

Starting with .NET version 6.0.300, I am getting a MSBuild error on my CI/CD actions in Github.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.

I found a reference to a breaking change in .NET 6.0.300 SDK which seems like it describes my issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/vs-msbuild-version

My pipeline is configured to use the latest point release of .NET 6 (6.0.x). I can pin this to v6.0.202 for a temporary fix. However, what is the recommended approach to resolving this issue? I set the version of .NET SDK, but I am not setting the version of MSBuild.

The command which is failing in the pipeline is

```
run: dotnet publish ./aspnet-core --configuration Release --no-build --output ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

The ./aspnet-core path is the root directory for my solution file which has multiple projects within it.

Comment: The error message couldn't be clearer. Change your command to `dotnet publish ./aspnet-core/someproject.csproj`.

Answer (score 0):

Lex Li is correct. I added the directory for the specific project I wanted to publish and it works as expected. I did not have to specify the actual csproj file, just the directory containing the csproj file.